# Merging two pandas dataframes: if statement returns: "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm regularly producing complex datasets of genetic data. The datasets contain some id values, taxonomic information (e.g. phylum_name), **sample numbers (values are read numbers), and sequences (DNA sequences composed of a g t c)**. I'm working on a script to merge the "old" dataset (=`basefile`) with a newly produced dataset (=`newfile`).

a standard datasets looks as follows (example file, values not actual values):

```
from numpy import nan
import pandas as pd

file={'id': {0: 'A00379:62:HGV7WDSXX:2:1101:7545:1000_CONS_SUB_SUB_CMP',
  1: 'A00379:62:HGV7WDSXX:2:1101:16477:1000_CONS_SUB_SUB_CMP',
  2: 'A00379:62:HGV7WDSXX:2:1101:24795:1000_CONS_SUB_SUB_CMP',
  3: 'A00379:62:HGV7WDSXX:2:1101:16613:1016_CONS_SUB_SUB_CMP',
  4: 'A00379:62:HGV7WDSXX:2:1101:26702:1016_CONS_SUB_SUB_CMP'},
 'ali_length': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'sample:new1': {0: 6000000, 1: 20, 2: 5000, 3: 5, 4: 1},
 'sample:new2': {0: 0, 1: 10, 2: 3000, 3: 0, 4: 2},
 'sample:new3': {0: 100000000, 1: 5, 2: 2000, 3: 10, 4: 3},
 'order_name': {0: 'xxxx', 1: nan, 2: 'xxxx', 3: 'Xanthomonadales', 4: 'xxxx'},
 'phylum_name': {0: 'xxx',
  1: 'Proteobacteria',
  2: 'xxx',
  3: 'Proteobacteria',
  4: 'xxx'},
 'reverse_match': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'reverse_score': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'reverse_tag': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'scientific_name': {0: 'newxx',
  1: 'Proteobacteria',
  2: 'newxxxx',
  3: 'Xanthomonadaceae',
  4: 'xxxx'},
 'scientific_name_by_db:greengenes3': {0: 'newxx',
  1: 'Proteobacteria',
  2: 'newxxxxx',
  3: 'Xanthomonadaceae',
  4: 'xxxx'},
 'superkingdom_name': {0: 'Eukaryota',
  1: 'Bacteria',
  2: 'Bacteria',
  3: 'Bacteria',
  4: 'Eukaryota'},
 'tail_quality': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'tribe_name': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'sequence': {0: 'taccagggtttgctagaagtgttggtttcctgaaaaggattccttattccgcttctacaggtggtgcatagcag',
  1: 'tacccacctttgacatgtacggaagttgccagagatggatttgtgctcgaaagagaaccgtaacacaggtgctgcatggcc',
  2: 'taccagggcttgacatgtcacaaatctttctgaaaggaaagagtgccttcgggaatgtgaacacaggtggtgcaggccaa',
  3: 'tacctggtcttgacatgtcgagaactttctagagatagattggtgccttcgggaactcgaacacaggtgctgcatggct',
  4: 'taccagggtttgacatcctgcgaacccctgagaaatcggggggtgccctcgggaacgcagtgacaggtggtgggggggggg'}}

df_file = pd.DataFrame(file)
```

For now you can ignore columns `id, ali_length, reverse_match/score/tag, tail_quality, and tribe_name`. 
The `basefile` and `newfile` look similar in structure but the `newfile` will have new sample numbers and possibly new sequences. Important columns for this question are the columns starting with `sample:` and the `sequence` column.

***I want to merge two of such files based on similarity on the column ```sequence````. There are two possibilities:***

1) Some of the sequences of the new samples in the new datafile will already exist in the old datafile. If so, I want copy the value of the new samples in the new datafile for that particular sequence to the (newly created sample) columns in the old dataset for that sequence.

2) A sequence is present in the `newfile` which does not occur in the `basefile`. If so, I want to create a new row in the `basefile` for this new sequence and copy the values for the new samples in the `newfile` and give all the existing samples in ```basefile```` a 0 for this sequence.

For this I've written following code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

basefile = pd.read_csv("basefile.txt",sep="\t") #test "old" file
newfile = pd.read_csv("newfile.txt",sep="\t") #test "new" file

seq_col=basefile["sequence"] #all the occuring sequence of the basefile

new_samples=[sample for sample in newfile if sample.startswith('sample')] #retrieve all new sample names from the new file

for i in new_samples: #add the new sample names as columns to the basefile dataframe and give it 0 as starting value
    basefile[i]=0


for e in newfile.iterrows(): #iterate over the rows as one sequence per row

    new_seq=e[1]["sequence"] #for each row, assign the sequence from the newfile to variable new_seq

    if new_seq in seq_col.values == True: #check if the sequence occurs in the basefile, if True it is not a new sequence.

        for x in new_samples:
            basefile[basefile.sequence==new_seq][x]=newfile[newfile.sequence==new_seq][x] #I want to add the value of every new sample for the given sequence

    else: #if it is a new sequence, add the (new) sequence row of the basefile
        basefile=basefile.apppend(newfile.iloc[e[0]])
```

Running this script returns error: `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` at line

```
if new_seq in seq_col.values == True: #check if the sequence occurs in the basefile, if True it is not a new sequence.

        for x in new_samples:
            basefile[basefile.sequence==new_seq]
```

I googled this error and found this is an error thrown by `numpy`. However running `if new_seq in seq_col.values == True:` seperately returns `True`. So I don't get why I get this error with this code.

changing it to

```
if new_seq in np.all(seq_col.values == True):
```

does not work and returns error: `argument of type 'numpy.bool_' is not iterable`.

**easy expected output example:**

basefile:

```
sample1    sample2    sample3    sequence
10         15         5          A
2          2          1          B
10         20         25         C
```

newfile:

```
sample4    sample5     sequence
10         25          B
5          5           D
```

RUNNING CODE SHOULD RETURN:

```
MERGED FILE:
sample1    sample2    sample3    sample4    sample5    sequence
10         15         5          0          0          A
2          2          1          10         25         B
10         20         25         0          0          C
0          0          0          5          5          D
```

Ideas on how to get this code to work and what yields this error?

Comment: Try `np.all(seq_col.values)` or `seq_col.all()`?

Comment: answer of zhavorsa below gets rid of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you simply remove the `== True`

So, you should just have:

```
if new_seq in seq_col.values:
```

Python will automatically check if the condition is True or not, so writing `== True` is redundant. It still works if you write it though, but you should use paratheses:

```
if (new_seq in seq_col.values) == True:
```

Comment: thanks the code now does not stop because of an error. However it returns warning: ```__main__:26: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead``` I have read that this is generally now a problem. Do you know this?